# What happened to MiKTeX GUI based update tools?

Tags: installing, updating, update, miktex-update

[image]

Are they all gone and replaced by the `Console`?

I am very used to the "Update" GUI from the Start menu and other links. I can't seem to find them now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update manager and the other tools will be removed in the near feature. As said on https://miktex.org/announcement/mfc-deprecation:

> MiKTeX Console is now the tool of choice for most MiKTeX maintenance
>   tasks. The classic MiKTeX desktop applications (Settings, Package
>   Manager, Update Wizard) are considered deprecated and will be removed
>   in the future.
>
> More info: MiKTeX desktop applications were originally implemented on
>   top of the Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) library, a framework for
>   developing desktop applications for Windows. In the course of porting
>   MiKTeX to Mac and Linux, it was necessary to rewrite the three
>   applications.

Comment: I am outdated. MikTeX in Linux even with apt-get! But It scares me the time that I can ost with the dawn comparisons when probably is completely irrelevant  using one or another for real works.